# Dont redirect if parameter is set

Tags: .htaccess, parameters

I want to redirect a url except when there is a parameter named login with the value false.
Tested it on several regexp testers and it works like I want.
But when it comes to the server it doesn't.
I always get redirected to ?login=true.

Why?

```
RewriteRule   (.*)write((?!/?login=false).)*$     ?login=true   [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRule only matches against everything after the hostname and before the query string. You'll need to use RewriteCond and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !login=false
RewriteRule (.*)write$ ?login=true [L]
```

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.

Comment: hm but then there occures another strange thing. i have some more parameters after the login when i use your suggestion those parameters are not longer readable by my php.

Comment: Then use the flag `QSA`.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA this is only for Rewriting Rules but not for Conditions and since my rule gets interrupted by the conditions this wont work from my knowledge

Comment: @StefanHövelmanns The condition checks for a string `login=false` anywhere in the query string. If it matches anywhere in the query string, the condition should evaluate to false (because of the prefix `!`). `QSA` should append any parameters that were already in the request to the ones you define in the rewriterule.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule (.*)write$ ?login=true [QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !name=                      
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule (.*)write$ ?login=true [L]
```

made it like this now
works for me